# Rails Relation Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

so i'm working on a rails 4 app and i have two models a Developer and an App.

Basically i want a Developer to act as a founder and have multiple Apps and those apps belong to the Developer (founder). Then i want and app to have many collaborators and a collaborator belongs to many apps. Heres my code, is this right? An how would i lets say add a collaborator to an app?

App

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, class_name: 'Developer', foreign_key: :collaborator_id
has_and_belongs_to_many :founders, class_name: 'Developer', foreign_key: :founder_id
```

Developer

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :apps, foreign_key: :collaborator_id
has_and_belongs_to_many :apps, foreign_key: :founder_id
```

Relations Table

```
def change
create_table :apps_developers, id: false do |t|
  t.references :founder, references: 'Developer'
  t.references :collaborator, references: 'Developer'

  t.references :app
  t.boolean :collaborator_pending, default: :true
end

add_index :apps_developers, [:founder_id, :app_id], unique: true
add_index :apps_developers, [:collaborator_id, :app_id, :collaborator_pending], unique: true, name: 'index_apps_collaborators'
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HABTM for collaborators and `has_many` for founders, not the other way around.

The reason is the relationship between collaborators and apps is many-to-many, while the relationship between founders and apps is one-to-many.

/app/models/app.rb

```
Class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :founder, :class_name => 'Developer'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborators, :class_name => 'Developer'
end
```

/app/models/developer.rb

```
Class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps, :foreign_key => :founder_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apps, :foreign_key => :collaborator_id
end
```

As for your second question, this is how you can add a collaborator to an app:

```
app.collaborators << developer
```

Where `app` is an object of the `App` class and `developer` is an object of the `Developer` class.

Comment: Does this work if there could be more than one founder such as a co founder?

Comment: No. But then, you didn't mention that requirement in your question. If you need co-founders, then you're right to use HABTM between apps and founders. One thing's for sure, collaborators are most definitely HABTM.

Comment: Another thing you can do is add a second association for co-founders to my answer. An app would `belongs_to :co_founder, :class_name => 'Developer'` and a developer would `has_many :apps, :foreign_key => :co_founder_id`. This way you can use two different foreign keys and you'll be able to write `app.founder` and `app.co_founder`.

Comment: ok thank you, but if a collaborator is HABTM with an app then doesn't that mean that the collaborator actually owns that app. The collaborator should belong to the app right and the app should have many of them?

Comment: I'm just thinking that if a developer creates an app will they automatically be set as the founder if the collaborator has a HABTM because currently with an app having many collaborators which belong to an app, the founder defaults as the one who created it.

Comment: If you want each developer to collaborate on just one app at a time, then sure, use `belongs_to`. Otherwise, go the HABTM route.

Comment: i tried to add a founder in my control and i get 'ERROR:  column "developer_id" of relation "apps_developers" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "apps_developers" ("founder_id", "developer_id")...' when i run '@app = App.create(parameters).founders << current_developer', is there a reason why its looking for developer_id instead of founder_id?

Comment: Did you specify the correct foreign key for the relationship?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36182/discussion-between-depa-and-ny95)